# It's possible change a SQL query window tab name on left side as list?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2012. Usually query editor tabs looks like this:

```
| tab 1 | tab 2 | tab 3|
```

but I want like this:

```
| tab 1 |
| tab 2 | 
| tab 3 |
```

Comment: use union for this simple

Answer (score 0):

right click on any tab and select new horizontal tabs option